# cross origin .ico image

Tags: html, image, iframe, cross-browser, cross-domain

Google chrome doesn't seem to bother to display an <img> with cross origin src attribute.
Firefox does. So for Firefox one would need to use an iframe which works fine for .png images. But it turns out that Firefox doesn't handle well iframes with an .ico src attribute: Firefox simply doesn't seem to create the appropriate elements in the iframe.

So the question is: is it possible to display a cross origin .ico image in Firefox?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<img>`'s `src` doesn't have a cross origin policy by default. That's why you can link your images from almost everywhere (almost, because you can set your host not to allow hotlinking -maybe that's what appears here-).

Anyway, please, try to avoid the use of *.ico* in a `<img>` tag because it won't be shown in every browser as @Pekka said. Some will anyway because many software save *.ico* file as *.png* (kinda like a camouflage) but it still a trick...

The iframe trick won't work either.

In summary, use *.ico* only if you need to but avoid it if you want a nice compatibility with every browser.

Comment: That's correct, the problem lays on the fact .ico is not universally supported.

Answer (score 0):

> google chrome doesn't seem to bother to display an  with cross origin src attriubte.

that is definitely incorrect. Your problem probably doesn't have to do with the image's origin, but with the format. ICO is mainly a [Windows format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28file_format%29) and will not be reliably displayed across browsers.

The [Wikipedia browser comparison on image formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support) doesn't list ICO at all.

Comment: well, i made a working example at http://www.dooity.com: inspect the images in the footnote at the bottom. ok it is an <image> but in a previous version i used an <img> and i do remember that it worked.